# ASP.Net MVC in shared hosting environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

It's a very simple question, but I wasn't able to find exact answer.

Do you need to install anything extra besides .Net Framework 3.5 and IIS7 to run ASP.Net MVC applications?

Hope it will be useful to other people too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use any third party libraries, then no.

The host has to have the .NET 3.5 **SP1** installed.

However you need to be aware of the trust level issues. Most shared hosts run in medium trust mode. Although this will suffice for the MVC itself, it may not for your other code. If you use reflection for example, you will need the full trust enabled.

Basically this simple code may get you into trouble:

```
object something = 5;

if (something is int)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Check your code and choose the host wisely.